# How do I use GridSearchCV to predict X_test for each iteration?

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

[image of graph i want to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyBRX.png)

I'm thinking of plotting a graph where the x axis is the complexity of the graph (e.g., n_neighbors in KNN), and the y_axis is the error (like mean squared error).

I'm currently using Grid Search CV and I realise that for `.cv_results_` , they only show the train data error.

```
KNN={
    'classifier':  [KNeighborsClassifier()],
    'classifier__n_neighbors':  [i for i in range (10, 200, 10)],
}

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps = [('classifier', KNN["classifier"][0])]

    )

grid_serach_knn = GridSearchCV(pipeline, [KNN], n_jobs=-1).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

`grid_serach_knn.cv_results_` would give me

```
'split0_test_score': array([0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96,0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96]), 
'split1_test_score': array([0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96]), 
'split2_test_score': array([0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96,0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96]), 
'split3_test_score': array([0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96]), 
'split4_test_score': array([0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96]), 
'mean_test_score': array([0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96,0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.96]), 
'std_test_score': array([9.84e-04, 8.70e-04, 1.30e-03, 1.09e-03, 7.68e-04, 9.61e-04,1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16,1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16, 1.11e-16,1.11e-16]), 
'rank_test_score': array([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7])}
```

firstly, i don't understand the different kinds of test scores. are they the training scores? if they are, what metrics are they using? accuracy/r^2/precision/recall?

secondly, how would i use `model.predict(X_test)` for each iteration to find the error for the test dataset so that i can plot the graph at the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> firstly, i don't understand the different kinds of test scores. are they the training scores? if they are, what metrics are they using? accuracy/r^2/precision/recall?

No, these are the validation scores. Each value is an array of 19 numbers, corresponding to the 19 different values for `n_neighbors`. You did not specify the `cv` parameter, so `GridSearchCV` defaulted to splitting your training set into 5 parts and doing 5 runs, each time using one of those parts as the validation set and the other 4 to train the model. This is what the "split0" to "split4" names refer to. The values are all accuracy scores.

For example, "'split0_test_score': array([0.97, ..." tells you that after training the model with `n_neighbors=10` on 80% of the training data, according to the first split, the model classified 97% of the instances in the remaining training data correctly.

The mean scores over the 5 splits and the corresponding standard deviations and ranks are also included in the results.

> secondly, how would i use `model.predict(X_test)` for each iteration to find the error for the test dataset so that i can plot the graph at the top?

Note that `GridSearchCV` has a parameter `return_train_score`. Quoting from the scikit-learn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> **return_train_score : *bool, default=False*** 
> If `False`, the `cv_results_` attribute will not include training scores. Computing training scores is used to get insights on how different parameter settings impact the overfitting/underfitting trade-off. However computing the scores on the training set can be computationally expensive and is not strictly required to select the parameters that yield the best generalization performance.

So you can set that to `True` to get the training scores and plot those as one curve, in addition to the validation curve. Scikit-learn even has a [`validation_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html#sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve) function to help with this, and an [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-validation-curve-py) of how to use it.

However, note that the plot you show does not mention (cross-)validation at all, and you say you have a separate test set that you want to use for the plot. So instead of doing any cross-validation, a simpler approach is to iterate over the `n_neighbors` values, fit the model to the entire training set each time, and compute the accuracy scores of that model (e.g. with [`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)), one for the training set and one for the test set. This approach is possible in your case, because the goal is to produce the plot, and you are not interested in any further hyperparameters apart from `n_neighbors`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! 

Should I be placing all my data into the GridSearchCV instead of placing X_train and y_train only? 

I am interested in all hyperparameters, but only am using n_neighbors as an example.

Comment: Yes, if you do not need the independent test set to get an unbiased estimate of the accuracy on new data, then you can combine the training and test sets as input for the cross-validation in this case.